# nodejs: check until URL get's online

Tags: node.js, infinite-loop

I need a "forever-watchdog" for checking if an URL is reachable or not. My case is that I have to see if a media stream gets online, and if, I would need to run a shell-script. If it's not reachable (404'd), I would keep trying again in x seconds.

Could anyone please guide me into the right directions, in terms on modules, or flowing? I had problems with resolving the destination with the

```
isReachable = require('is-reachable');
```

module.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can send requests to the URL repeatedly. Something like this:

```
//I don't know how you create nodejs server, I just leave out that part.
//I use request module.  sudo npm install --save request
var request = require('request');
var URL = 'https://www.google.com';
var X = 5000; //5 seconds
var sendRequest = function(){
  request(URL, function(error, response, body){
    if(response.statusCode === 200){//If good
      runScript(); //This is the function you write to run sh
    }
  setTimetout(sendRequest, X);//run the function again no matter what
  });       
}
sendRequest();
```

If you want a better forever loop, I suggest you use promise.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');
var options = {
  uri : 'https://www.google.com',
  json : true
};
var X = 5000; //5 seconds, the actual time is 5 seconds plus the time to resolve
var sendRequest_promise = function(){
  //return a request promise
  return rp(options).then(function(response){
    return response;
  });
};
var sendRequest = function(){
  sendRequest_promise().then(function(response){
    if(response.statusCode === 200){
      runScript();
    }
    setTimeout(sendRequest(), X);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How do I make this an forever-loop that checks every 5 seconds if it's (still) alive?

Comment: With `X = 30` this will check every 30 milliseconds, not 30 seconds. set `X = 30000` for every 30 seconds.

Comment: @chr_lt_ney Then you just need to get rid of the 'else', answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Try this, should resolve you task

```html
'use strict';
const co = require('co');
const request = require('request');
const exec = require('child_process').exec;

let getRemoteSourceStatusPromise = function(urlForCheck){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      request(urlForCheck, function(error, response){
          console.log('send request...');
          if(error)
              return reject(error);

          let result = false;
          console.log('Resource response statusCode ' + response.statusCode);
          if(200 === response.statusCode){
            result = true;
          }
          return resolve(result);
      });
  });  
};
let callShScriptPromise = function(){
    let shScriptPath = './script.sh';
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log('Calling sh...');
        exec(shScriptPath,
            function (error) {
                if (error)
                   return reject(error);
                resolve(true);
            });
    });
};
let sleep = function (sleepInterval) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('sleep...');
            resolve();
        }, sleepInterval);
    });
};
let loopGenerator = function* (urlForCheck, sleepInterval){
    let bShScriptStarted = false;
    while(true){
        let bSourceStatus = yield getRemoteSourceStatusPromise(urlForCheck);
        if(bSourceStatus === true){
            if(!bShScriptStarted)
                bShScriptStarted =  yield callShScriptPromise();
        }else{
            bShScriptStarted = false;
        }
        yield sleep(sleepInterval);
    }
};


//Starting loop
co(loopGenerator('http://google.com', 30000))
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

Comment: Generator Function  has infinit loop with calling promises (for get sorce status, sleaping, and calling you bash script). "Co"  is used for starting generator

Comment: You can set 5000 instead 30000. And script will check status every 5 seconds (and will start sh if need it)

Comment: Thanks! This gave me a bunch of problems though, such as error messages for let, const, yield, 'function *', etc. Am I missing something?

Comment: @chr_lt_ney which version of nodejs do you use? Try lastest stable

Comment: I did. But the script dies if the url is not available initially, when I started the script.

Comment: I updated and all is well, except for one part: the url I check is, if it's online, an audio-stream. That means that I do not get an HTTP code such as the 200 I expect, until the stream is shut down. Can I somehow only ping the url, or use something similar to curl -i?

Comment: what status code did you receive in response (when requesting woring stream)? Can you show me working link on stream?

Answer (score 0):

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const checkIfOnline = (() -> { 
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
        rp( url ).then( response => {
            // this is where you run your script
            resolve();
        }).catch(error=>{
            setTimeout( resolve(checkIfOnline()), 5000 );
        });
    });
})();
```